# Where does the returned value from e.g. a method call go if not filled into a declared variable of expected type?

Tags: c#, .net, return-value

We are not forced to fill the returned value from e.g. a method call into a declared variable of expected type, but what happens to it in that situation?

Where does the following returned value go/What happens to it: ?

```
decimal d = 5.5m;
Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

---

Obviously, if I wanted to see the result from the method call I would do the following:

```
decimal d = 5.5m;
decimal d2 = Math.Round(d, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // Returns 6 into 
                                                           // the variable "d2"
```

(This question is NOT specific to value types, but also reference types)

Comment: Maybe you need to ask Alice... +1 for the interesting question

Comment: Into the dark void of lost, forgotten, and unreferenced return values.

Comment: @George
LOL! You just made my day :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It gets popped from the [execution stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/11/28/why-have-a-stack.aspx):

```
IL_000A:  call        System.Math.Round
IL_000F:  pop
```

If it's a reference type, the reference will be popped from the stack, and the object itself will eventually be collected by the GC (assuming that it has no other references).

Comment: What's the IL stack though? would be nice to read more, but I can't seem to find anything about it

Comment: @Shai: Execution stack may be a better term.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/11/28/why-have-a-stack.aspx

Comment: On the x86 platform, the return value will usually wind up in a CPU register (EAX or ST(0) [for doubles/floats] are the classic choices in other compilers; not sure if the CLR jitter uses the same convention); if it's not stored anywhere, it will eventually be overwritten by other uses of the register.

Comment: What about value types? Do they get popped too?

Comment: @Alex: Yes; `double` is a value type.

Answer (score 1):

The returned value of the method pushed on the `caller stack`. Will be it used, or not is a matter of the code of the `caller`.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
void Main()
{
   var result = MyCoolFunc(10, 20); {1}
}

int MyCoolFunc(int prm1, int prm2) 
{
   return (prm1 + prm2);
}
```

*Pesudo example of some VM, skipping intial code*

```
VM_PUSH 10 //prm1 stack state is {10}
VM_PUSH 20 //prm1  stack state is {10,20}
VM_EXEC MyCoolFunc //call function which executes what need, removes from stack those 2 values and pushes result of the function execution. stack state is {30}
```

if we do not write on line {1} `var result`, it ends here, if yes 
there should be something like this

```
VM_ALLOC result //allocate space for result
VM_GETFROMSTACK // get content of the stack to result
```

**The VM code is a PSEUDO CODE and doesn't exists in real life. It used only to give an example**